# Flutter: Update the position of marker

Tags: flutter, google-maps

How can I update the position of a marker in Google maps? What's the method using to update it in flutter? I'm using the API data.

Comment: I found the solution, i used Timer

Answer (score 0):

**update the marker position on new Latlang thats coming from api data. so simply
make marker and show the marker accroding to the latlang.**

```
    function changeMarkerPosition(marker) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.748774, -73.985763);
        marker.setPosition(latlng);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting new latlng add new marker

```
setState(() {
_markers.add(Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId('marker_Id'),
    position: UPDATED_LAT_LNG,
    icon: sourceIcon));)}
```